# Getting 404 Error when trying to create a Lead object in SalesForce API

Tags: api, sobject, connected-apps

I'm sending a POST request from a connected app to try and create a Lead object in my company's dashboard. Here is the URL that I'm using to post:

```
https://${MyOrganization'sBaseURL}.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Lead/
```

I'm getting a 404: Not Found response when I ping that endpoint. The base URL works fine to get an access_token:

```
https://${MyOrganization'sBaseURL}.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your organization on Summer 22 (v55) release

Comment: Do you know where I would be able to check that?

I don't think we are. Another support thread suggested I try v54.0 in the URL instead, and I got a new error: 400 Bad Request.

That would lead me to believe we're on 54.0.

Comment: status.salesforce.com

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.